# Statements equivalent to claim that a space $X$ is a $T_1$ space

Tags: general-topology

Following a reference from "Elementos de Topología general" by Angel Tamariz and Fidel Casarrubias.

> **Definition**
>
> A topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is $T_1$ if for any different point $x$ and $y$ there exists two open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $x\in U\setminus V$ and $y\in V\setminus U$.

Well with this definition I must prove the following theorem.

> **Theorem**
>
> The following statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. $X$ is a $T_1$ space;
> 2. any $A\subseteq X$ is the intersection of the open sets that contain it;
> 3. for any $x\in X$ it result that $\{x\}$ is the intersection of the open sets that contain it.

Unfortunately it seems I have some difficulties: so could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll introduce an extra equivalence

> 1.' For all $x \in X$, $X \setminus \{x\}$ is open.

1 implies 1': Fix $x \in A$ and let $y \neq x$. We have some open $V_y$ such that $y \in V_y$, $x \notin V_y$ by 1. But then $y \in V_y \subseteq X\setminus \{x\}$ and it follows that $X\setminus \{x\}=\bigcup \{V_y: y \neq x\}$, a union of open sets and hence open.

1' implies 2: Let $A$ be a subset of $X$. Define $A'=\bigcap \{O: O \text{ open }, A \subseteq O\}$, and we need to show $A=A'$. First note that $A \subseteq A'$ is clear by definition, as $A$ is a subset of all sets (at least one, $X$ e.g.) we're taking an intersection of. Now, if $x \notin A$, then $O=X\setminus \{x\}\supseteq A$ is open by 1' and $A' \subseteq O$ by definition ($O$ is one of the sets we're intersecting!) and so $x \notin A'$. It follows that $A' \subseteq A$ and we're done.

2 implies 3: trivial, take $A=\{x\}$.

3 implies 1: If $x \neq y$ apply 2. to $\{x\}$ and we have some open set $O$ that contains $x$ but does not contain $y$ (otherwise $y$ would have been in the intersection of 3. which it is not, as it's not $x$!) and vice versa applying it to $\{y\}$ we again find $O'$ containing $y$ but not $x$ in the same way.

Note that $1'$ leads to the standard equivalence that all singletons are closed (by complementation) and hence that all finite subsets are closed)..

Answer (score 0):

1 $\Rightarrow$ 3:
Be $(X,\tau)$ a $T^{1}$ topological space. Suppose that 3 is not verified then $\exists x \in X :$ the intersection of all open that contain x is $\neq \{x\}$ and we denote for $C$ this intersection.
Be $y \neq x \in C$ then we have that for all open $V : x \in V$ then $y \in V$ so $y \in V \cap U, \forall U$ open that $y \in U$ and this implied that $(X,\tau)$ is not $T^{1}$. Absurd !!!!!!!!!

3 $\Rightarrow $ 1:

Be $x,y \in (X,\tau) : x\neq y$. Then exists a open $V : x \in V$ and $y \not\in V$ and a open $U : x \not \in U$ and $y \in U$ because if that two open no exists we have that intersecction of all open that contains $x \neq \{x\}$ and the same with $y$.